# Importar modulo desde una carpeta del mismo nivel

Tags: python

Mi situación es la siguiente, necesito importar un archivo que contiene varias funciones que se encuentra en una carpeta la que llame para el ejemplo **"modules"**, donde se encuentra el archivo a importar al que llame **"module.py"**, al mismo nivel que la carpeta **"modules"** se encuentra la carpeta **"tests"** donde se encuentra un archivo **"try.py"**, que es al cual necesito importar algunas funciones de **"module.py"**.

Adjunto aquí una captura de pantalla:

[image]

He visto varios métodos de hacer esto, como usar el modulo sys o crear un archivo **init**.py en la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo que se desea importar, que pienso que es la manera mas 'elegante', por lo que he decidido usar esta forma, en este caso he creado el archivo en la carpeta **"modules"**.

El problema llega cuando voy a importar al archivo **"try.py"** algunas funciones desde **"module.py"**, la forma de usar la importación con **init**.py para que python lo reconozca como modulo, he visto que es llamar al archivo así:

```
from [carpeta] import [archivo]
```

y luego llamar a la función:

```
archivo.funcion
```

o tambien:

```
from [carpeta.archivo] import [funcion]
```

pero al ejecutar la función importada me da este mensaje de error:

```
from modules.module import funcion

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```

Sin embargo también añadí un archivo en la misma carpeta **"modules"** llamado **"test.py"**, desde el cual si importo de la siguiente manera, si funciona:

```
from [archivo] import [funcion]
```

Cual es entonces la manera correcta de importar los archivos que contengan funciones u otro tipo de sentencias como clases o variables

Gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Funciona desde la misma carpeta ya que al realizar la importación se busca el nombre de la carpeta o archivo en la carpeta actual. Al realizarlo desde la carpeta `test` se estaría realizando lo siguiente `en la carpeta actual busca una carpeta llamada modules y busca el archivo module e importa funcion`. Si vas a realizar test te recomiendo usar `pytest`. Además, para resolver tu problema deberías hacer `from ..modules.module import funcion`

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar algo como esto:

```
from ..modules.module import my_function
```

Espero te sirva. saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, sin embargo el problema persiste y no logo entender el porque.
Si hago una importación relativa como comentasteis ambos, @maucoder @Christian
,el error es diferente y python dice lo siguiente: 
`from ..modules.module import my_function
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Lo que vi en otras soluciones de Stackoverflow en inglés, puede que tengas una versión de Python anterior a la 3.8, y esto no es valido.

Puedes checar este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60593604/importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package

espero te sirva